# Sound Earplug buzzling noise on Ubuntu with Asus UX501vw

Tags: 16.04, sound

I am using Asus Zenbook UX501VW.
Recently, I installed **Ubuntu 16.04** and up-to-date kernel.
I eventually fixed some issues such as maximum cpu speed problem, wifi issue after updating latest kernel. 
I used to install kernel 4.3.5 because I read an article that someone recommended this kernel version to fix some issue.However, this downgraded kernel has also problem. So, I installed latest stable kernel **4.8.6.**

In fact, I am satisfied with this kernel except for one issue.
After suspend(sleeping) my laptop and waking up, buzzling noise(like cpu core-wire noise) from earplug starts right away. This issue doesn't exist when I reboot. Only after suspend sleeping.
I did many instructions to fix this issue such as updating nVidia driver, and Mute microphone something with Alsa  ... But still the noise problem exists. 
I think that this issue is related to not reload some driver after waking up from suspend. I really don't know now.

Please help me to solve this issue...

- Asus Zenbook UX501VW
- Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop Ver.
- Kernel Ver : 4.8.6-040806-generic #201610310831 SMP Mon Oct 31 12:33:48 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 370.28 from nvidia-370

  ```
  id:
  multimedia
  description:    Audio device
  product:        Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id:    
  1f.3
  bus info:
  pci@0000:00:1f.3
  version:        31
  width:  64 bits
  clock:  33MHz
  capabilities:   pm msi bus_master cap_list
  configuration:
  driver  =       snd_hda_intel
  latency =       32
  resources:

  irq     :       135
  memory  :       dd428000-dd42bfff
  memory  :       dd400000-dd40ffff
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this tricky issue my self after performing all  semi-solutions available on the Internet by myself.

The way to resolve this is just type on the Terminal.

**> sudo alsa force-reload**

That's IT.

Good Luck!